# Too many open files even with O_EXCL

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that is able to determine if a process that calls it is the first to do so, without the use of any locks.

This is my current implementation.

```
def is_first_process(path):
    filename = os.path.join(path, "first.file")
    try:
        fd = os.open(filename, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
        os.close(fd)
        return True
    except FileExistsError:
        return False
```

I test the above function like this:

```
def test_is_first_process():
    path = "/tmp/first_process"
    shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
    process_list = []

    def helper(fn, arg, shared_list):
        shared_list.append(fn(arg))

    for _ in range(1000):
        makedirs(path)
        manager = Manager()
        results = manager.list()
        for i in range(1000):
            p = Process(target=helper, args=(is_first_process, path, results))
            p.start()
            process_list.append(p)

        for p in process_list:
            p.join()

        assert results.count(True) == 1
        shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
```

For large m*n the test errors out with the following error:

`E OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

But not for smaller values (m*n < 100).

My understanding of the os.O_EXCL flag is that it raises the `FileExistsError` if it already exists.

Is my understanding of this flag incorrect?
How do I correctly implement and test a function that can determine the first process that writes to a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misinterpreting the error you're seeing. The error message about `Too many open files` means what it says, that you're opening too many files at the same time. It does not necessarily that your one file is being opened more than once at a time.

It may be that the multiprocessing code that's handling the inter-process communication is causing problems with the 1000 separate processes that you're trying to start all at once. That's a lot of processes!

Many operating systems limit how many files each process can have open, and often also limit each user logged in, so even opening only a few files in each of a huge number processes might be a problem. It may be that you could modify the limits on your system, using `ulimit -n` or a similar configuration program.

But the real question is, why do you think you need to test with 1000 processes at a time? Even on a large system, you're probably not going to have that many CPU cores, so most of those processes will necessarily be sleeping, while only a few of them run. I'd suggest doing your testing with a number of processes that is at most a small multiple (e.g. 2x) of your system's number of cores, any more is just wasting your time.